# Find and Find Next for RichTextBox

Tags: vb6, richtextbox

```
richTextBox1.Text = "Where there is a will there is way";
```

I just want to change the both `is` only red color.

I know how to change the first `is`, but i don't know how to change the second `is`.

```
RichTextBox1.SelStart = RichTextBox1.Find("is")
RichTextBox1.SelLength = 2
RichTextBox1.SelColor = vbRed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261638%28v=vs.60%29.aspx):

> If the text searched for is found, the Find method highlights the
>   specified text and returns the index of the first character
>   highlighted. If the specified text is not found, the Find method
>   returns 1.

I'm assuming it's a typo and the return is -1 rather than 1 if the text isn't found, so, in your code:

```
Dim idx As Integer 
Dim start As Integer

Do
    idx = RichTextBox1.Find("is", start) '// First time through start at beginning
    If idx = -1 Then Exit Do
    RichTextBox1.SelStart = idx
    RichTextBox1.SelLength = 2
    RichTextBox1.SelColor = vbRed
    start = idx + 1 '// Set the start for .Find to the next character
Loop
RichTextBox1.SelLength = 0 ' Clear the selection
```

Comment: @SatheeshKumar: Glad to hear it. Feel free to hit the check beside the answer to mark it as accepted. See [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)